# Cookie manually set with a Variable (in value)

Tags: jmeter

I have a variable CCODE.

In my Cookie Manager, I set:

```
Name = AAA
Value = ${CCODE}
```

Results Tree shows `AAA=${CCODE}`.

I'm very sure the variable CCODE exists because I can use it elsewhere.

The following in user.properties:

```
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
CookieManager.check.cookies=false
CookieManager.allow_variable_cookies=true
```

How to solve this ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

- JMeter's test elements [execution order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)
- JMeter [Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

Given the `${CCODE}` variable exists and has its respective value (you can check it using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter)) JMeter will send the relevant cookie along with the request.

[image]

Comment: I notice that you added the variable in the Test Plan while I've extracted it from a previous step using Regular Expression Extractor.  So I added the variable to the Test Plan and it worked.  I've also added it as a User Defined Variable inside / outside the Thread Group and they both worked.  I verified using using Dummy Sampler before cookie setting.  I really need to extract the field from the Response Header.  I've read the scope and I still could not figure out why the extracted variable does not work.